Geom_label position_dodge not working as expected with coord_flip in Shiny
I have an app and the asterisks are postitioned perfectly without coord_flip:

But, I wanted to turn it into a row chart so I added coord_flip() to the ggplot code. Now the asterisks are completely off - everything else appears fine:

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?
My code is:
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput('cat', 'Select Category', unique(table_4_9$Hours_or_Inc)),
               pickerInput(
                 inputId = "controls",
                 label = "Show average of non-recipients",
                 choices = unique(table_4_9$variable),
                 multiple = TRUE,
                 selected = "Overall"
               ),
               checkboxInput("p_values", label = "Show p-value levels", value = FALSE),
               checkboxInput("error_bars", label = "Show 95% confidence intervals", value = FALSE),
               actionButton("Explain_p_values", "Explain p-values"),
               actionButton("Explain_error_bars", "Explain 95% confidence intervals")
             ),
             mainPanel(plotOutput('plot'))
           ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 observeEvent(input$Explain_p_values, {
    showModal(modalDialog(HTML(p_value_text)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$Explain_error_bars, {
    showModal(modalDialog(HTML(CI_text)))
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    cbPalette_4 <- c(
      "Overall" = "#999999",
      "Self Employment (Ag)" =  "#F0E442",
      "Self Employment (Non-Ag)" = "#0072B2",
      "Wage Employment" = "#D55E00"
    )
    
    fun_select_cat <- function(table, cat) {
      table %>%
        filter(Hours_or_Inc == cat)
    }
    
    table_4_filtered <-
      fun_select_cat(table_4_9, input$cat) |>
      ungroup()
    
    control_y <- table_4_filtered %>% pull(Control) |> unique()
    
    title <- if (input$cat == "Hours") {
      paste(input$cat, "Worked in the Past 12 Months", sep=" ")
    } else {
      paste(input$cat, "/Profits (USD) Earned in the Past 12 Months", sep = "")
    }
    
    layer_error <- if (input$error_bars) {
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = higher), width = 0.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
    }
    
    layer_p <- if (input$p_values) {
      column_y_text <- if (input$error_bars) {
        "higher"                                  #if p-values and error_bars checked then add stars at higher CI otherwise at the obs
      } else {
        "new_est"
      }
      max_y_text <-
        table_4_filtered |>          # if asterisks column not NA then either put asterisks higher than error bars if error_bar checked
        filter(!is.na(Sig)) |>                   # or put it at bar height if not checked
        pull(column_y_text) |>                   # keep the height of tallest bar
        max()
      
      list(
        geom_label(
          aes(
            label = Sig,
            y = .data[[column_y_text]],
            group = variable
          ),
          vjust = 0,
          fill = NA,
          label.size = 0,
          label.padding = unit(10, "pt"),
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
          na.rm = TRUE
        ),
        if (!is.na(max_y_text))
          expand_limits(y = c(0, max_y_text * 1.05))              # if tallest bar has asterisk then expand limit
      )
    }
    
    layer_h <- if (!is.null(input$controls)) {
      geom_hline(
        data = {
          table_4_filtered %>% filter(variable %in% input$controls)
        },
        aes(yintercept = Control, color = variable),
        linetype = "dashed",
        linewidth = 1
      )
    }
    
    table_4_filtered |>
      ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = new_est, fill = variable)) +
      geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette_4) +
      scale_color_manual(values = subset(cbPalette_4,
                                         names(cbPalette_4) %in% input$controls)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma(), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme_classic() +
      scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(
          hjust = 0.5,
          size = 14,
          face = "bold"
        ),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12)
      ) +
      layer_p +
      layer_error +
      layer_h +
      guides(color = "none") +
      labs(title = title, x = NULL, y = NULL) +
      coord_flip()
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

and dput(table_4_9):
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("Long Term", "Short Term", "Lump Sum"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = c("Overall", "Overall", "Self Employment (Ag)", 
    "Self Employment (Ag)", "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", 
    "Wage Employment", "Wage Employment", "Overall", "Overall", 
    "Self Employment (Ag)", "Self Employment (Ag)", "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", 
    "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", "Wage Employment", "Wage Employment", 
    "Overall", "Overall", "Self Employment (Ag)", "Self Employment (Ag)", 
    "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", "Wage Employment", 
    "Wage Employment"), Control = c(2752.04, 2517.63, 1197.39, 
    491.62, 522.78, 589.43, 1031.87, 1478.71, 2752.04, 2517.63, 
    1197.39, 491.62, 522.78, 589.43, 1031.87, 1478.71, 2752.04, 
    2517.63, 1197.39, 491.62, 522.78, 589.43, 1031.87, 1478.71
    ), Estimate = c(61.92, 503.4, 66.07, 4.99, 95.7, 692.69, 
    -99.85, -275.53, 79.42, 1274.8, 24.94, 41.59, 81.79, 875.18, 
    -27.3, 272.42, 110.23, 671.6, 88.24, 94.1, 90.72, 215.67, 
    -68.73, 323.03), SE = c(67.8, 314.8, 53.18, 59.81, 54.74, 
    284.59, 46.45, 105.3, 78.02, 571.56, 37.81, 50.11, 51.89, 
    520.79, 40.01, 149.54, 77.59, 365.13, 40.92, 52.68, 45.69, 
    285.76, 47.18, 217.4), Sig = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "�\u0088\u0097", 
    "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
    "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", NA, "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
    NA, NA, NA, "�\u0088\u0097", NA, "�\u0088\u0097", NA, "�\u0088\u0097", 
    "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
    NA, NA, NA), Hours_or_Inc = c("Hours", "Income", "Hours", 
    "Income", "Hours", "Income", "Hours", "Income", "Hours", 
    "Income", "Hours", "Income", "Hours", "Income", "Hours", 
    "Income", "Hours", "Income", "Hours", "Income", "Hours", 
    "Income", "Hours", "Income"), new_est = c(2813.96, 3021.03, 
    1263.46, 496.61, 618.48, 1282.12, 932.02, 1203.18, 2831.46, 
    3792.43, 1222.33, 533.21, 604.57, 1464.61, 1004.57, 1751.13, 
    2862.27, 3189.23, 1285.63, 585.72, 613.5, 805.1, 963.14, 
    1801.74), lower = c(2681.072, 2404.022, 1159.2272, 379.3824, 
    511.1896, 724.3236, 840.978, 996.792, 2678.5408, 2672.1724, 
    1148.2224, 434.9944, 502.8656, 443.8616, 926.1504, 1458.0316, 
    2710.1936, 2473.5752, 1205.4268, 482.4672, 523.9476, 245.0104, 
    870.6672, 1375.636), higher = c(2946.848, 3638.038, 1367.6928, 
    613.8376, 725.7704, 1839.9164, 1023.062, 1409.568, 2984.3792, 
    4912.6876, 1296.4376, 631.4256, 706.2744, 2485.3584, 1082.9896, 
    2044.2284, 3014.3464, 3904.8848, 1365.8332, 688.9728, 703.0524, 
    1365.1896, 1055.6128, 2227.844)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    Hours_or_Inc = c("Hours", "Hours", "Hours", "Hours", "Income", 
    "Income", "Income", "Income"), variable = c("Overall", "Self Employment (Ag)", 
    "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", "Wage Employment", "Overall", 
    "Self Employment (Ag)", "Self Employment (Non-Ag)", "Wage Employment"
    ), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 9L, 17L), c(3L, 11L, 19L), 
        c(5L, 13L, 21L), c(7L, 15L, 23L), c(2L, 10L, 18L), c(4L, 
        12L, 20L), c(6L, 14L, 22L), c(8L, 16L, 24L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))


When using coord_flip you have to use hjust=0 instead of vjust to align to the left after flipping.
